# Rounding off doesnt work for higher numbers in Python

Tags: python, numpy, decimal

I am trying to figure out a way to round off a list of numbers in my text file.
input:  -3.21804657e+163
expected output:   -3.21

I had tried the above code with math.ceil , round and even the decimal operators but it does not work, what is the issue here. I believe my number had some string values as well. How can I remove it.

Comment: If the suggestion from [Cow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11355926/cow) does not answer your question, you should add your code to your question to get valuable advices

Comment: What does this have to do with numpy?

Comment: -3.22e163 is a very large number, it's equivalent to -3220 followed by 160 zeros.  that's nowhere near -3.22 so rounding operations wouldn't ever give that value back, why are you expecting that value?

Comment: No one is sure as to how/why you should have `-3.21` as the answer. The number is huge. unless you divide by 1e161 to reduce it. But how/why do you need `-3.21`?

Comment: **@ZubairAhmed Ansari** could you add a little more about the issue you're having and why you're trying to reduce such large number(s)? your Question doesn't seem to match the duplcate mark and could be re-opened, but we need more information about it to help!

Comment: Hello, This is the received(raw) signal I got from gnuradio. And my final objective was to create the heat map out of these data as it would represent the RSSI values use for localisation in my case. However, I already got the answer as how to make it smaller! thanks to @Loïc Ribere for providing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

-3.21804657e+163 is a valid number in python, this is a float, not a string.

You can use the builtin round() to round a number in Python.
Documentation for [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) .

In your case, you want to provide to round() a negative integer argument.
For instance :

```
great_number = -3211

print(great_number)

print(round(great_number, -2))
```

Gives :

```
-3211
-3200
```

But it looks like you don't want to round your number, but to truncate it instead.

If I take your number for reference :

```
number = -3.21804657e+163
rounded_number = round(number, -161)

print(rounded_number)
```

Output :

```
-3.22e+163
```

Which is, indeed, rounding the number.

If you only want to keep the first digits of your number :

```
number = -3.21804657e+163
number_first_digits = float(str(number)[0:5]))
```

or :

```
number = -3.21804657e+163
number_as_string = str(number)
truncated_number = float(number_as_string[0:5])
```

Let's print it :

```
print(truncated_number)
OUTPUT : -3.21
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be between how numbers are *stored* and how they are *represented* see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) .. however removing the huge factor feels wrong as you're dividing it by `10**163`

```py
>>> int(-3.21804657e+163)
-32180465699999999141771606176124228046112212284965248942113261148899212884335346334945453074432647994974947747216467907068897673480370028582631422393879546925416448
```

Note that this has lots of extra noise in it due to how the value is briefly stored as a float, but is extremely close to the expected value

```py
-32180465700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

If you're reading a file by lines, you can parse the data more cleverly to prevent this

```py
import re
RE_sci_notation = re.compile(r"^(-?\d)\.(\d+)e([+-]\d+)$")
data_lines = []
path = input("enter the path to read: ")
with open(path) as fh:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fh, 1):
        try:
            float(line)
        except ValueError:  # probably not a number
            print(f"not a number on L{lineno}: {line}")
            continue
        line = line.strip()  # any leading spaces and trailing newline
        match = RE_sci_notation.match(line)
        if match is None:
            print(f"unexpected line format on L{lineno}: {line}")
            # maybe save the initial int parse
            continue
        a, b, c = match.groups()  # unpack regex
        if int(c) < 1:  # only allow large values
            print(f"only handles large values for now L{lineno}: {line}")
            continue
        zeroes = int(c) - len(b)
        data = int(a + b + "0" * zeroes)
        data_lines.append(data)
print(data_lines)
```